# Building Android project with ant having a library project dependency on another library project

Tags: android, ant

I have maybe this not so common setup:

(> = dependency)
Android project > Android library project 1 > Android library project 2
So I have an Android library project which has a dependency to another library project.

When I'm building project in Eclipse everythings works fine but I cannot get my build working with Ant.

First Ant compiles Android library project 2 which generates a classes.jar and puts this file in the bin folder.
Then Ant tries to compile the Android library project 1 but then I'm getting errors becouse it is missing classes from Android library project 2.

Well this is not so weird becouse the jar file is not included in the libs folders.
But in project.properties i've made a dependency to the library project 2 so why does Ant not copy the classes.jar to the libs folders of library project 1?

Well I can think of a solution to use an Ant task to copy the file to the libs folder, but then I have to modify the build.xml which I do not prefer.

** EDIT

The problem is that the R class is missing, when I look in classes.jar this java file does not contain the R class. So my solution would proberly not work.

Comment: Got the same problem. Recently tried to recompile on old project with current sdk tools and hit this problem. Previously when the build used source code merging this wasn't an issue but now that compile jars and for some reason leave out the R class. None of the "answers" are real answers. In my case I have a paid and free version of app and using the recommended pattern of having two projects and a common library. I don't see it as a good pattern that the top level projects must manage all the dependencies of the common library.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour was caused by a change in R17 of the build tools: http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

In a nutshell: R files for libraries are no longer packaged in the classes.jar for that library. However, since the pareent.R for the parent-library (project1 in your example) also contains the resource-references for the 'child' library (project2 in your example), you don't have to refer to the child-R anyway.

Replace all project2.R-import statements in project1 with project1.R import statements and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

For ant to compile add dependency in ant.properties.
eg:

```
android.library.reference.1=../path/to/library
```

Comment: Yes i've made this reference. This works for a normal Android project but not when i make a reference from a library project to another library project.

Comment: Did you add ant.properties in your library project? you can also try to update the library project by running `"android update project -l "lib ref" -p .` in your ref lib root folder

Comment: Android udpate project did not create a ant.properties. I added the ant.properties manualy but nothing changed. I don´t know if ant reads the file becouse i´m building from another folder (Android normal project)

Comment: I'm encountering same issue once I add the google-play-services-lib into my project.  Can't seem to figure out how to configure the ant.properties to let Jenkins build it.  Probably gonna switch to Maven since it seems to handle these issues better.

Comment: I am having the same issue with team city.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a very brittle setup - you may have good reason for this, but could you instead decouple the libraries dependence on each other?

For example; implement a [bridge pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) to translate the calls between both libraries, and make the calling Android project attach them. This way, you have no code in either library that depends on the other, and the only project that needs to handle dependency setup is your main project.

One of the main reasons for using a library is to make the code re-usable, this approach ensures someone (you, a colleague, your successor...) could plug in just one library and create their own implementation of the other one.

Here is another good article on applying the bridge pattern in Java: http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-bridge

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem was that the R class was missing.
So i removed the R class dependency between the two library projects.
I don't know if this is fixable but i think it is bad practice any way.

Without this dependency Ant builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but like me, others might be banging their head on this...

The official answer is "it cannot be done", specifically:

> At build time, the libraries are merged with the application one at a time, starting from the lowest priority to the highest. **Note that a library cannot itself reference another library and that, at build time, libraries are not merged with each other before being merged with the application**.

(extracted from the official documentation: ["Referencing a Library Project"](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)).

Which means that anything goes, as there is no "clean" way to do it with the tools (and dirty methods are in order).

Hope it helps